# Update label inside loop

Tags: vba, excel

**The issue**

I have a form which runs a loop processing items when activated. The visual part of the form contains a text, which should display *"Processing X og Y items*", to show the progress of the loop. The issue is that rather than updating the visual part, the loop causes Excel to stop responding while running. How do I prevent this from happening?

Edit: I might want to add that the functions `DataFunctions.getStatus()` as well as all the `Process.*()` functions contains some database (T-SQL) communication.

---

**The code**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim currentStatusCode As Long, _
        agCount As Long, _
        currentAg As String

    'Get array and find its size
    agArray = getAgArray()
    agCount = UBound(agArray) + 1

    'Loop through the list of items and process them one by one.
    For i = 0 To agCount - 1
        updateLabel i + 1, agCount  '<-- This is where the visual is updated
        currentAg = agArray(i)

        currentStatusCode = DataFunctions.getStatus(currentAg)

        If currentStatusCode = 100 Then
            Process.validate currentAg
            currentStatusCode = DataFunctions.getStatus(currentAg)
        End If


        If currentStatusCode = 101 Then
            Process.create currentAg
            currentStatusCode = DataFunctions.getStatus(currentAg)
        End If

        If currentStatusCode = 103 Then
            Process.createSomethingElse currentAg
            currentStatusCode = DataFunctions.getStatus(currentAg)
        End If

        If currentStatusCode = 104 Then
            Process.changeStatus currentAg
            'No need to get the new status here
        End If

    Next i      

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest trying `DoEvents` and/or `Me.Repaint`

Comment: `Me.Repaint` did the trick - thank you very much! If you post this as a "real" answer, then I can accept it, such that others may be helped as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Me.Repaint` should force the form to redraw itself, thereby updating the label. You may also want to add `DoEvents` if your routine shows 'Not responding' a lot.